# conexão php mysqli (Connection refused)

Tags: php

Estranho do nada meu php não conecta com meu mysql, o phpMyAdmin funcina normalmente.

Rodei um `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status` e esta tudo ok.

Meu php esta assim:

```
$ip_bd_mysql_master = '127.0.0.1';
$login_bd_mysql_master = 'root';
$senha_bd_mysql_master = '123456';

// Conexão
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($ip_bd_mysql_master, $login_bd_mysql_master, $senha_bd_mysql_master, 'teste');
```

O erro que tenho é esse:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/html/bd.php on line 6
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

A versão do meu php é PHP 7.2.13-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 08:07:36) ( NTS )

Comment: Tenta colocar o `host` vazio : `$ip_bd_mysql_master = '';`

Comment: com ele vazio o erro muda: `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in`

Comment: Tem certeza que os dados de acesso estão corretos?

Comment: Sim, via terminal eu conecto de boa, usando `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` a unica alteração que fiz ontem no meu pc foi configurar um segundo site na porta 81 do acpache, mas acho que isso não tem nada a ver. E como falei o phpMyAdmin conecta de boa.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss vlw pela ajuda, o erro era no meu mysql. Alterei o arquivo `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`. Troquei a linha `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` para bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro era no meu mysql.

Alterei o arquivo `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

Troquei a linha `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` para `bind-address   = 0.0.0.0`

Depois reiniciei o mysql e deu certo.